# How to build and use a Meteor package on an arm?

Tags: meteor, compilation, package

I tried to host a **Meteor** server from my Rasperry pi. Until now I was good to go with [4commerce build](https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor). I would like to use the **CollectionsFS**, which is not build for arm processors. I want to build the package myself and need some guidance on how to proceed. It seems like that I only need to build the npm package [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream)

> cfs:gridfs have no binaries, but it depends on two npm packages ("gridfs-stream" and "mongodb"), you need rebuild that packages.

due to [CollectionFS Issue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/813)

Until now I tried to clone the *gridfs-stream* package and `make` the makefile, but it seems some important files are missing?

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha: not found
```

So how do I compile the package? 
Do I have to use the source from Github? Lastly when the package is compiled how will I include it within my Meteor dependencies?